# NSLog memory address

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

I try to NSLog the name of the presenting view controller:

```
NSLog(@"presentingViewController is: %@", self.presentingViewController);
```

but all I get is: "presentingViewController is: UITabBarController: 0x71393d0"

I know I need to create an description but I don't know how and where. I don't have a custom class for the UITabBarController.

Thanks for you help and don't beat me up for question which might be too easy for pros.

Comment: As Viktor pointed out, just create a category on UITabBarController and override the method: -(NSString *)description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without custom class you could overwrite the method in the UITabBarController with a category.

Example:

```
//UITabBarController+Description.m
@implementation UITabBarController+Description (UITabBarController)

- (NSString *)description {
    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The tabBarController with backgroundImage: %@",     self.tabBar.backgroundImage];
    return output; 
}
@end
```

Documentation from Apple here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: This is better done in a subclass if at all possible. If Apple implements `-description` in a category themselves (which is legal, can freely change from SDK to SDK, and not easily detected by the developer), then the above is undefined behavior. Categories are for adding methods, not overriding methods.